# Statement .with builder in Adonisjs to select specifict column doesn't work

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, adonis.js

I want to get data from table relation in Adonisjs. I using `.with` function to get data from table relation but just for some column, but it doesn't work.

My controller code like this:

```
const cart = await Shop.query()
            .with('products',(builder)=>{
                builder.select('id','product_name')
            })
            .select('id_shop')
            .fetch()

        return response.json({
            status:true,
            message: false,
            data: cart
        })
```

But the result of code above is only `id_shop`, like this:

```
[

    {
       'id_shop': '1'
       'products': []
    },
    {
       'id_shop': '2'
       'products': []
    }


]
```

**edited**

I added my shop's model here:

```
class Shop extends Model {

    static get table()
    {
        return 'shop'
    }

    static get primaryKey()
    {
        return 'id_shop'
    }

    products ()
    {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Product','id_shop', 'shop_id')
    }
}
```

And my product's model:

```
class Product extends Model {

    static get table()
    {
        return 'product'
    }

    static get primaryKey()
    {
        return 'id_product'
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you please share your models?

Comment: i already share my models too @CrBast

Comment: Share your migration schema for shop, product table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put wrong hasMany relation in Model
hasMany relationship like this

```
 products ()
    {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Product','shop_id', 'id_shop')
    }
```

or change in controller where you use builder change like this

```
const cart = await Shop.query()
            .with('products',(builder)=>{
                builder.select('id_product','product_name')
            })
            .select('id_shop')
            .fetch()
```

change you **id** to **id_product**
you can try this

Comment: but it's still doesn't work, product's output still empty [ ]